# R: biomaRt package missing probe ids?

Tags: r

I got a problem with biomaRt package, when i was looking up entrez ids for affymetrix hgu133a probe set ids. For example biomaRt couldn't find "206323_x_at".
When i listed all the probe ids in affy_hg_u133a list there was only 19872 probe ids, however there are 22245 probes on HGU133a (or 22313 with control probes). Is something wrong with the script or this database is incomplete?

Thanks!

```
library(biomaRt)  
mart<-useMart("ensembl", dataset="hsapiens_gene_ensembl")  
affyids="206323_x_at"  
getBM(attributes=c('affy_hg_u133a', 'entrezgene'), filters = 'affy_hg_u133a', values = affyids, mart = mart)  
[1] affy_hg_u133a entrezgene   
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

hgu133a<-getBM(attributes='affy_hg_u133a', mart = mart)
dim(hgu133a)
[1] 19872     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to work for this probeset. We can obtain an answer with

```
library(hgu133a.db)
myprobeset  = "206323_x_at"
genes <- mget(myprobeset,hgu133aENTREZID)
```

We can test another probeset

```
affyids = c("218471_s_at")
getBM(attributes = c("affy_hg_u133a", "entrezgene"), filters =  "affy_hg_u133a",values = affyids, mart = ensembl)

myprobeset  = "218471_s_at"
genes <- mget(myprobeset,hgu133aENTREZID)
```

So this seems to be a case where two different sources of data give different answers. This happens every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

The `probemapper` package may be of use for this particular need, as well. It's available in R and also has an online interface.

Here are the results for your particular gene:
[qbrc.swmed.edu/probealignment/#probe=1005849](http://qbrc.swmed.edu/probealignment/#probe=1005849)

Interpretation: The vendor and Bioconductor agree that your probe aligns to Entrez ID 4983, but BLAST shows some other potential alignments (which can likely be ignored if you just care about the Vendor's annotation).

Comment: Thanks, your package seems quite useful, has somebody used it in a published article (besides yours)?

Comment: We've seen quite a bit of traffic on the web service, but I'm not aware of any publications which used it currently.